# Run migrations with table prefix - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I read that I could use:

```
config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "so_"
```

In Rails 2.

But what I need is a prefix applied to all migrations when I run them, how could achieve that?

Comment: Do you mean, when you say `create_table :something`, it should create a table with name `so_something`?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be following this plan:

1. Run migrations
2. Load schema file appending a prefix in tables and indexes, also, changing Schema by Migration.

From what I [read](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/) `table_name_prefix` no longer exists in Rails 3.2.16.

Answer (score 1):

When you generate a model with a namespace it will prefix the table name with that namespace.  For example

```
rails g model Admin::User user:string
```

will generate a migration

```
class CreateAdminUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :admin_users do |t| 
      t.string :user

      t.timestamps
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: thanks, but I did not mention that have already models and migration files, I want to copy a set of tables inside a bigger application with a prefix

Comment: hi? I just want to ask if is this a good practice for creating prefixes?